# Hi, I have falshed o/s for my rasberry pizero W on my 32gb sd card which contained my lots of data,So all I want to ask can I recover it back?

Tags: pi-zero-w, database, recovery

I want to know that does flashing formats existing data,if no how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

When you flash an sdcard any existing data is overwritten and gone for ever. Most flashing programs warn you of this before writing